# How to discover Bluetooth Low Energy Device(BLE) from Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-phone-8.1

I am writing a Silverlight Windows Phone 8.1 application, I am trying to connect with Bluetooth Low Energy(BLE) device from Windows Phone 8.1, the device is "HEART RATE", but I'm not getting the result. See my code below.

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(GattDeviceService.GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid
                           (GattServiceUuids.HeartRate));
   if (devices.Count > 0)
   {

   }
}
```

I have also added capability in appmanifest file.

```
<Capabilities>
 <Capability Name="internetClient"/>
    <m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.genericAttributeProfile">
      <m2:Device Id="any">
      <m2:Function Type="name:heartRate" />
       <m2:Function Type="serviceId:0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" />
     </m2:Device>
</m2:DeviceCapability>
```

Everything seems fine, but I don't get the output. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The heart rate sensor has to be paired first in the "settings->Bluetooth" on your phone.

Comment: user3224741, is it possible to get BLE Device Data like MAC Address and Name etc. wtihout PAIRING? Thanks for ur response.

Comment: It might be visible in the advertisement data.