# How to check that Bluetooth Low Energy is supported in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-phone-8.1

I have Nokia Lumia 625, which was basically Windows Phone 8, but recently I updated my phone with 8.1, so how do I know if the device is BLE supported or not?
If yes, then how can I discover nearby BLE devices?

Comment: Are you just asking if your phone does? [According to Nokia](http://www.nokia.com/global/products/phone/lumia625/specifications/), it has Bluetooth 4.0

Comment: @ShawnKendrot thank you brother, but is there a way by using code, so that device is BLE supported or not?

Comment: @ShawnKendrot and how do I discover nearby BLE devices using code?

Comment: Have you tried the [BluetoothLEDevice class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothledevice.aspx)?

Comment: @ShawnKendrot yes I have tried,but fails, somebody said that you have to first pair with BLE device, is there any way without pairing? Thanks!!

Comment: why did you post the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928264/how-to-discover-bluetooth-low-energy-deviceble-from-windows-phone-8-1